# How do I set the initial database size with IndexedDBShim?

Tags: javascript, ios, html, indexeddb, web-sql

I am using the polyfill [IndexedDBShim](http://nparashuram.com/IndexedDBShim/) to create a database on iOS Safari 7.1. However, it throws an error in indexeddbshim.min.js (line 118) and then tells me:

```
"Application cache update failed, because size quota was exceeded."
```

despite the entire app being 1.06 MB. But I think indexeddbshim is requesting too large a size to start (I believe in iOS 7.1, you need to first request less than 5MB in WebSQL to start before increasing it after)

All I can find is this:

```
var request = indexedDB.open( "mydbname", 1.0 );
```

If I try adding in a size variable it doesn't work, and neither does the "const" I found someone else mention online:

```
//Neither of these options work
var DEFAULT_DB_SIZE = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
var request = indexedDB.open( "mydbname", 1.0, DEFAULT_DB_SIZE );
```

How can I set the WebSQL initial size?

Answer (score 1):

Inside the indexeddbshim.js file, there is a line like this:

```
var DEFAULT_DB_SIZE = 4 * 1024 * 1024;
```

which corresponds to an initial size of 4MB (in version 2.2.1 of the unminified file it is in line 2996).

Edit this line inside indexeddbshim.js to be a different value, and then retry.